# Mini Map in InfowWindow for direction route

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working in Google Map v3(actually migrating V2 to V3), and trying to customize the Infowindow of the Direction Service.
I am able to display the Direction using Origin, Destination and waypoints.
My Map displayed the route correctly with Marker (green marker with A, B, C... text).
By default, On click of teh marker infowindow will display address of that marker.
I want to customize it, so that on click of marker it should disply mini map of that location in Infowindow with more zoom.
I am able to do some progress, but the problem here is, 
- Marker is changed to red pointing marker instead of Green marker (with A, B, C...text)
- whichever the marker I click, infowindow will open on the last marker
- Once marker is clicked it will display minimap, but on close and again click of that marker it will display address (default behaviour)
- my code is actually overwriting the green marker with red pointed marker

Can soboby help me how to fix all these issue
Below is my code:

```
       function CreateDirection (arrWaypoints) {
            if (!this.directions) {
                this.directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

                var origin = arrWaypoints[0];
                var destination = arrWaypoints[arrWaypoints.length - 1];

                var tripWaypoints = [];

                for (var i = 1; i < arrWaypoints.length - 1; i++) {
                    tripWaypoints.push({
                        location: new google.maps.LatLng(arrWaypoints[i].hb,     arrWaypoints[i].ib),
                        stopover: true
                    });
                }

                var myMap = MyMap.getMap();
                var steps = [];

                this.directions.route({
                    origin: origin,
                    destination: destination,
                    waypoints: tripWaypoints,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                    unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC
                }, function(result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

// directionDiv div element in my page                           

directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionDiv"));
                        directionsDisplay.setMap(myMap);
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        function CreateMiniMapInfoWindow (wayPointsArray) {
            for (var i = 0; i < wayPointsArray.length; i++) {
                var myMap = MyMap.getMap();
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: wayPointsArray[i],
                    map: myMap
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                var myOptionsMini = {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: wayPointsArray[i],
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }

               var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var minimap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById    ("minimap"), myOptionsMini);

                    document.getElementById("minimap").style.display = 'block';
                    minimap.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                    var minimapDiv = document.getElementById("minimap");
                    infowindow.setContent(minimapDiv);
                    infowindow.open(myMap, marker);
                });
            }
        }
```

I need the solution for:
- How to get customized infowindow (with minimap) for all the markers
- How to put the green markers with text A, B, C...
[image]
Attached image is what I am getting from the above code
I hope my question is clear.
Please let me know if anyone have any inputs.

Thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 1):

Pass the following object as argument to the DirectionsRenderer:

```
{markerOptions:{clickable:false,zIndex:1000}}
```

It will have 2 effects:

1. the custom markers will be placed behind the A,B,C-markers created by the DirectionsRenderer(currently they are still present, but behind your custom markers)
2. the markers created by the DirectionsRenderer are not clickable, the underlying custom markers are able to receive the click.

**another option(I would prefer it):** set the `suppressMarkers`-option of the DirectionsRenderer to true and use the A,B,C-markers for your custom markers(e.g. https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker_greenA.png , https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker_greenB.png )

**Related to the infoWindow:**  all you need is 1 infoWindow with 1 map for all markers. Observe the click-event of the markers and when it occurs open the infoWindow and center the map inside the infowindow at the markers position(may be retrieved inside the click-callback via `this.getPosition()`)

**Note:** instead of using your predefined waypoints you better parse the route returned by the directionsService to place the custom markers at the exact positions(these may differ from your predefined waypoints)